# xml - Empty String attribute value xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

The attribute `match` may not always contain a value , it should allow Empty String :

```
<template mode="on" match="">
</template>
```

To validate that the previous code , I'm using the following xsd
Here is my xsd :

```
<xs:element name="template">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="mode" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="match" use="optional">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:union memberTypes="xs:string emptyString"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:simpleType name="emptyString">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="0"/>
        </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

In the validation process against the xsd, I got the following error message :
 `no viable alternative at input ' <EOF> '` .

The following code doesn't show me any error.

```
<template mode="on" match="aaa">
</template>
```

Any Idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your complete XSD is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="template">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="mode" use="optional"/>
      <xs:attribute name="match" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:union memberTypes="xs:string emptyString"/>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="emptyString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:length value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Then your XML is valid against your XSD, both with `template/@match=""` and with with `template/@match="aaa"`.  There is nothing wrong with either your XML or your XSD.

Note, though, that a `xs:string` can already be empty without the extra `xs:union` with `emptyString` part.

Note, too, that your error message does not look like one generated by common validating XML/XSD parsers.  I suspect that your message is actually originating from another program, or that you've failed to produce a true MCVE of your issue.

Comment: You're right, I have another top layer that produces, thanks.